# Selecting Specific tds with ID using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with tds, each having different ID. To be specific IDs are dates. I am trying get those elements using the ID with and trying to add a class.

```
$(elements).not(".ui-select").addClass("ui-select");
```

I am passing element as,  `$("#" + date)` where date has the Id for each TD. However I am unable to get this done using the above.

Comment: try doing `console.log(elements)` and see what it shows

Comment: can you share the value of `date` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing the element as $("#" + date) your function should look like this:

```
function someFunction(element){
 element.not(".ui-select").addClass("ui-select");
}
```

call the function like so: someFunction( $("#" + date))

if you are passing it as a string, ie someFunction("#" + date) you can use the notation you have above:

```
function someFunction(elementID){
  $(elementID).not(".ui-select").addClass("ui-select");
}
```

I feel that what you are getting is someFunction($('#' + date)):

which results in:

```
 function someFunction(elementID){
      $($("#1234")).not(".ui-select").addClass("ui-select");
    }
```